# FB Checkbox Plugin was rendered but not showing in browser

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have implemented Facebook Checkbox Plugin according to Facebook's documentation and its working fine for some browsers and not visible some browsers but the plugin was rendered. Also i have checked FB checkbox code in firebug its is available in but the plugin only not visible. I have tried to clear the cache and cookies that time also not working.

Please see the Images. [Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AWi7.png) - [Not Visible in FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8aDc.png)

Thanks

Comment: Found the problem? have the solution?

Comment: @TBE : Not Yet, Did you know anything? Please help me.

Comment: I ended up setting the width and hight with javascript of the surrounding elements of the checkbox iframe

Answer (score 0):

In our project we have identified several failure points and compiled [troubleshooting tips](https://docs.amio.io/docs/facebook-messenger-entry-points-from-webpage#section-troubleshooting). In your case I would check the `allow_login` parameter. If it is set to `false`, **you will need to have a valid Facebook user session (i.e. not logged in as a page) otherwise the plugin will be hidden**.

Comment: I have checked and i have set allow_login as true only. Also it was not rendered some browsers only for some time only,

Comment: @Vinod, can you check that `user_ref` is always uniqly generated? (Even for every single page refresh!)

Comment: yes it was always unique for every user at every time. If not means the status of check box plugin will be hidden. But here it shows "Plugin was rendered". Please check the image which i have attached(Not Visible in FF). It was not showing where i have placed.

Comment: One thing, I am also facing the issue, in Internet Explorer with Angular version of facebook plugin is not show,up but yes the component loads